# How to fix "unexpected indent" error on a python column that isn't indented

Tags: python

My terminal is producing the error "unexpected indent" at the start of my for loop, when it is not indented at all in my editor. How can I fix this? See code below:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'BE110FinalProject.xlsx')
type(wb)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row in sheet.iter_rows('K{}:K{}'.format(258,sheet.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        if (cell.value):
            numerator = float(cell.value.split(':')[1])
            denominator = float(cell.value.split(':')[0])
            japanOutput.write(numerator + '/' + denominator + '\n')
        else: 
            japanOutput.write('\n')
```

Comment: Please make sure you have not mixed spaces and tabs while indenting.

Comment: @KarthikRavindra the line where the error is is not indented at all. On all lines after, I used tabs

Comment: Python is pretty specific on consistency in tabs and spaces. Please do a file wide search and stick to one or the other. That should fix the issue

Comment: very difficult to reproduce your error. So we can only guess. Try unindenting all the code for a few lines around the offending line and reintroduce all the indentation. Sometimes it gets rid of whatever is causing the problem.

Comment: please paste original source code to a online paste bin, and paste whole error message.

Comment: I unindented all of the lines and then reindented and the issue seemed to fix itself. Thank you all

Comment: It is best to write Python code in an editor that automatically converts tabs to spaces (with 4 being the default). Tabs are bad news in Python source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have spaces instead of tabs.
Python tends to be picky when it comes to tabs and spaces.
One thing to try would be removing your indentations and making sure you use tabs.
I hope this helped!